# How can I add a "display none" option to this "hcsticky" jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I modify this code so it hides ID "#gfoptions" when the item reaches "top:45"?

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("#gformdiv").css('z-index','99999').hcSticky({noContainer:true, top:45});
jQuery(".media-modal").css('z-index','999999');
});
```

I tried adding this line but it did not work:

```
jQuery("#gfoptions").css({display: none});
```

Comment: Tried `jQuery("#gfoptions").css('display','none');` or `jQuery("#gfoptions").hide();`?

Comment: Since none is a String if should be `jQuery("#gfoptions").css({display:"none"});`

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can "unhide" it once the user scrolls back up the page. I would like to only hide the element when it hits the sicking point "top:45".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn off the sticky, try this:

```
jQuery("#gformdiv").hcSticky('off');
```

In your case You have written the wrong syntax. It should be like this:

To Hide:

```
jQuery("#gfoptions").css({display:"none"});
```

or

```
jQuery("#gfoptions").hide();
```

To Show:

```
jQuery("#gfoptions").css({display:"block"});
```

or

```
jQuery("#gfoptions").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use hide and show

```
$( ".target" ).hide(); //adds the css style display none
$( ".target" ).show(); // removes the css style display none attribute
```